# from pil import image not working in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, anaconda, python-imaging-library

I have already installed pillow and I am trying to import Image as from PIL import Image.

However, it is giving me the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b7f01c2f8cfe> in <module>
----> 1 from PIL import Image

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in <module>
     92     # Also note that Image.core is not a publicly documented interface,
     93     # and should be considered private and subject to change.
---> 94     from . import _imaging as core
     95 
     96     if __version__ != getattr(core, "PILLOW_VERSION", None):

ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (C:\Users\Murali Manohar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PIL\__init__.py).
```

But I can import and use the module in PyCharm without any errors. I have tried installing the module using pip and conda. I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling pillow. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Try updating the package `pip install -U Pillow`

Comment: Did that. Tried uninstalling PIL also. Still not working.

Comment: Just want to make sure, the error exists when you try to import the library from IPython right? Is it inside a Jupyter Notebook? Could you please check the PyCharm Python Interpreter path?